# Numpy indexing - Using an unraveled index for basic indexing

Tags: python, numpy

If I have the following 4D array:

```
mat = np.array(np.arange(27)).reshape((3,3,3))
[[[ 0  1  2]
  [ 3  4  5]
  [ 6  7  8]]

 [[ 9 10 11]
  [12 13 14]
  [15 16 17]]

 [[18 19 20]
  [21 22 23]
  [24 25 26]]]
```

and the following unraveled index:

```
ind = np.unravel_index([7], mat.shape[1:])
(array([2], dtype=int64), array([1], dtype=int64))
```

what is the best way to access

```
mat[:, 2, 1]
[ 7 16 25]
```

using the unraveled index? I am looking for a generic solution to this issue where the number of dimensions `mat` has can vary.

I am aware that I could do something like this:

```
new_ind = (np.arange(mat.shape[0]),) +  ind
mat[new_ind]
[ 7 16 25]
```

but I was wondering if there is way to do this which does not require the explicit construction of a new index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do need to construct a new indexing tuple:

```
In [8]: ind=np.unravel_index([7,8],(3,3))                                       
In [9]: ind                                                                     
Out[9]: (array([2, 2]), array([1, 2]))
In [10]: (slice(None),*ind)                                                     
Out[10]: (slice(None, None, None), array([2, 2]), array([1, 2]))
In [11]: np.arange(27).reshape(3,3,3)[_]                                        
Out[11]: 
array([[ 7,  8],
       [16, 17],
       [25, 26]])
```

The `Out[10]` is equivalent to adding a `:` to your unraveled indices:

```
In [12]: np.s_[:,[2,2],[1,2]]                                                   
Out[12]: (slice(None, None, None), [2, 2], [1, 2])
```

Comment: Thank you, I did not consider the use of slice(None), much nicer than calling arange.